# What is the best way to fill D3 node circles with images?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Attempting to learn from the master I see Bostock generating this code:

```
<circle transform="translate(651,665)" class="g-person-target" r="22.5" style="stroke-width: 5px;"></circle>
```

to create [the elements in this example](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/02/20/movies/among-the-oscar-contenders-a-host-of-connections.html?_r=0).

But where is he getting the actually person's picture from? That I don't see.

Just looking for the best way to add images dynamically (not a single, fixed image) to the nodes of a Force Layout, e.g. Facebook profile pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the *"best"* but [this approach seems to work](http://plnkr.co/edit/p98Ss9m8zH8LAk8pBPdl?p=preview).

```
groups.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://graph.facebook.com/hannahymiller/picture?type=small")
  .style
    'clip-path': 'url(#clip)'
```

Still interested to know if there are more optimized solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is where he is getting the images from

http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/01/07/movie-network/72ae3b8d92ecc7a67c00babd2a75f34bfdacb3a7/mugs.jpg

in this part of the code

```
    personDot.append("image")
          .attr("xlink:href", "http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/01/07/movie-network/72ae3b8d92ecc7a67c00babd2a75f34bfdacb3a7/mugs.jpg")
          .attr("x", function(d, i) { return -mugDiameter / 2 - mugDiameter * (i % 9); })
          .attr("y", function(d, i) { return -mugDiameter / 2 - mugDiameter * (i / 9 | 0); })
          .attr("width", 9 * mugDiameter)
          .attr("height", 6 * mugDiameter)
          .attr("clip-path", "url(#g-mug-clip)")
          .style("pointer-events", "none");
```